# tablename alias in attribute name

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas, hash-map

I have dataframe like this:

```
date        tableName                attributeName
2019-03-29  [order as o, costumer]   [costumer.customerID, o.orderID]
2019-03-30  [customer c, payment]    [payment.paymentID, c.firstName]
...
```

I have a function that map the tableName to attribute, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def countTableAttribute(dataFrame, tableName, attributeName):
    a       = (dataFrame[tableName].values.tolist())
    r       = re.compile(r'\b(as|\s)\b',re.IGNORECASE)
    alias   = list((x,n) for x in range(len(a)) for n in a[x] if bool(r.search(n)))
    df3     = (pd.DataFrame(dataFrame[tableName].values.tolist(), index=dataFrame.index).stack().str.split(' as | ', expand=True)).dropna()
    if alias != []:
        d   = dict(zip(df3[1], df3[0]))
    else:
        d   = dict(zip(df3[0], df3[0]))
    dfs     = pd.DataFrame(columns=[-1,0,1])
    for i in range(len(dataFrame)):
        for x in dataFrame[attributeName][i]:
            if not '.' in x:
                ser = pd.Series([dataFrame['date'][i],dataFrame[tableName][i][0], x], index=dfs.columns)
                dfs = dfs.append(ser, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                ser = pd.Series([dataFrame['date'][i],x.split('.')[0], x.split('.')[1]], index=dfs.columns)
                dfs = dfs.append(ser, ignore_index=True)
    dfs.columns         = ['Date','tableName','attributeName']
    dfs['tableName']    = dfs['tableName'].replace(d)
    dfs                 = dfs.groupby(['Date','tableName','attributeName'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='Count')
    return dfs
```

so the output is like this:

```
   date        tableName   attributeName  count
2019-03-29     order       orderID          1
2019-03-29     costumer    customerID       1
2019-03-30     customer    firstName        1
2019-03-30     payment     paymentID        1
```

But as this is my first try, I need an opinion about what I've tried, because my code runs slow.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) can format your code to be more idiomatic.
- [`flake8`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8) can check your code for remaining non-idiomatic code.
- [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy/) can enforce [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to make it more obvious what the code is meant to do.
- Names like `a`, `r`, `d` and `dfs` are unhelpful. Naming is a hard skill to learn, but is enormously helpful in making code more readable and therefore maintainable.
- `if not '.' in x:` etc looks like it might be a good candidate for a separate function - it doesnt't take too many inputs, returns only one thing (`dfs`), and is short.
- It looks like you are doing a lot of conversions: `dataFrame[tableName].values.tolist()`, `list(…)`, `dict()`. I'm not familiar with Pandas, but I expect you can speed things up significantly by not converting values.